# Update cell value when user change values from that cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to update bind property value when user change a cell value by entering some text by keyboard. I've wrote code that shows bind property value and working fine. but i want to know how to update a cell value when user enter some text in particular cell of a particular row.

Let suppose user want to change Quantity. On entering some value into Quantity cell, how to reflect these changes to bind property value and update datagrid.

Note: also guide how to get newly entered value by user

```
<DataGrid  DataGridCell.Selected="DataGrid_GotFocus" SelectionUnit="Cell" 
                   SelectionMode="Single" Name="Datagrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                   PreviewKeyDown="Datagrid_PreviewKeyDown" 
                   CurrentCellChanged="Datagrid_CurrentCellChanged" SelectionChanged="Datagrid_SelectionChanged" SelectedCellsChanged="Datagrid_SelectedCellsChanged">

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Code, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Price" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding UnitPrice, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sub-Total" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding SubTotal, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

i've implemented curruntcellchanged event that works fine. This works as on Enter key, they get value from database and update bind property values. 
Now, afterwards if user change Quantity then how to reflect this changes towards bind properties.

```
 private void Datagrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("cell chnage");
            //Datagrid.BeginEdit();
            if (Datagrid.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                DataGridCellInfo cell = Datagrid.SelectedCells[0];

                var generator = Datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator;
                int columnIndex = cell.Column.DisplayIndex;
                int rowIndex = generator.IndexFromContainer(generator.ContainerFromItem(cell.Item));

                int counts = Datagrid.Items.Count - 1;
                //MessageBox.Show("total counts: " + counts.ToString() + "Selected index " + rowIndex.ToString() + " column index: " + columnIndex);

                string code = ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Code;
                Database database = new Database();
                database.DBOpen();

                SQLiteDataReader sQLiteDataReader = database.GetWhere(Database.TABLE_ITEMS, Database.CODE_ITEMS, code);
                while (sQLiteDataReader.Read())
                {
                    string name = sQLiteDataReader.GetString(2);
                    string desc = sQLiteDataReader.GetString(6);
                    string unitPrice = sQLiteDataReader.GetInt64(8).ToString();
                    string quantity = "1";
                    //string subTotal = (double.Parse(quantity) * double.Parse(unitPrice)).ToString();
                    //grossAmount = grossAmount + Double.Parse(subTotal);

                    Item item = new Item()
                    {
                        Code = code,
                        Name = name,
                        Description = desc,
                        Quantity = quantity,
                        UnitPrice = unitPrice,
                        //SubTotal = subTotal
                    };
                    ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Code = code;
                    ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Name = name;
                    ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Description = desc;
                    ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Quantity = quantity;
                    ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).UnitPrice = unitPrice;
                }
                database.DBClose();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution as,

```
 private void Datagrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
TextBox quantity = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
                DataGridColumn dgc = e.Column;

                if (Datagrid.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataGridCellInfo cell = Datagrid.SelectedCells[0];

                    var generator = Datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator;
                    int columnIndex = cell.Column.DisplayIndex;
                    int rowIndex = generator.IndexFromContainer(generator.ContainerFromItem(cell.Item));
                    ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Quantity = quantity.Text.ToString();

                    MessageBox.Show(quantity.Text.ToString());
                }
}
```